# How to add a closing shortcode to Wordpress template file?

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, shortcode

Okay, so you can add shortcodes to WP template files like:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[my_awesome_shortcode]'); ?>
```

but what if the shortcode is intended to wrap around content like this:

```
[my_awesome_shortcode]
Hey, this is the content within the awesome shortcode.
[/my_awesome_shortcode]
```

I'm a bit unsure how to put that into a template file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API#Enclosing_vs_self-closing_shortcodes

adding `$content = null` to the shortcut function should do the trick:

```
function my_awesome_shortcode_func( $atts, $content = null ) {
   return '<awesomeness>' . $content . '</awesomeness>';
}

add_shortcode( 'my_awesome_shortcode', 'my_awesome_shortcode_func' );
```

so that:

```
[my_awesome_shortcode]
Hey, this is the content within the awesome shortcode.
[/my_awesome_shortcode]
```

would result in:

```
<awesomeness>Hey, this is the content within the awesome shortcode.</awesomeness>
```

Comment: I think you missed the point on this question.  The question was, how do you put enclosing short code into a php routine?  You simply defined what enclosing short code is.  The solution from nicotr014 answers the question.

Answer (score 10):

The solution that worked for me was to combine shortcodes into a single string, so

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[my_awesome_shortcode]<h1>Hello world</h1>[/my_awesome_shortcode]'); ?>
```

will work!

If you have a long chain of shortcode commands you want to execute, create a separate string for them like this

```
$shortcodes = '[row]';
    $shortcodes .= '[column width="2/3"]';
        $shortcodes .= 'Content';
    $shortcodes .= '[/column]';
    $shortcodes .= '[column width="1/3"]';
        $shortcodes .= 'More Content';
    $shortcodes .= '[/column]';
$shortcodes .= '[/row]';
```

Then execute the entire thing like this

```
<?php echo do_shortcode($shortcodes); ?>
```